# Saving an image from picture box to png C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Good Day!
I am trying to save an image from PictureBox, however, it is giving me an error.

```
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\emo\hairs\Hair-01.png";
        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"C:\Coke\res1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

This is the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Emo.exe
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please help me identify my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting *NullReferenceException* exception because the *Image* property of the picturebox is null.

Try [PictureBox Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/zyc6weyd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\emo\hairs\Hair-01.png";
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
pictureBox1.Load();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"C:\Coke\res1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Another alternative is to use another [overload of the Load()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/f6ak7was%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
pictureBox1.Load(@"C:\emo\hairs\Hair-01.png");
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"C:\Coke\res1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```